# Why isn't my array holding values pushed in it when the page is reloaded?

Tags: php, arrays

In php I have a basic array in 1 file that starts out empty:

```
$array= array();
```

I have that file included in the next file; in this file every time the page loads (because it’s a landing page for a form submission) I want to add a certain piece of  the information submitted to the array

```
$array[]=$var;
```

And this works. However what I do not understand is when I echo the array to test it to see if it is holding the values, it is only holding the values for the current addition, it does not remember all the previous times the variable was added to the array.
 (I know you may think it will be long array but later on in the project I am going to remove/unset values from the array based on conditions but that’s not the point now) 
Why isn’t the array remembering al the values pushed into it?

Comment: PHP is stateless. That's *very* important tounxerstand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time your php script runs, it starts completely from scratch. Any variable or array you create are reset to their original values.

If you want to store the array values, you need to place the data somewhere else. Usually the first step for beginning PHP developers is to store them in a database like MySQL or Sqlite.